# Python custom module and import

Tags: python

I am following [this](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) example on how to package a python module. But installing my built package with pip, when I tried to use it, while the following works.

```
from towel_stuff import towel_utils

x = towel_utils.has_towel()
print(x)
```

And this also works,

```
import towel_stuff.towel_utils

x = towel_stuff.towel_utils.has_towel()
print(x)
```

I don't understand, why the following doesn't work.

```
import towel_stuff

x = towel_stuff.towel_utils.has_towel()
print(x)
```

Normally, for example if we want to use `os.path`, we don't need to write `import os.path`, but just `import os` is enough. So, with my built package, why do I have to give the full package path?

Of course I can use `from towel_stuff import *` to import everything, but was just curious why we don't need to give the full path for standard packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following structure:

```
towel_stuff
----__init__.py
----towel_utils
```

When you use `import towel_stuff`, the only file executed is `__init__.py`, so if you haven't imported `towel_utils` in `__init__.py`, it is not accessible at all.

So in short, when you use `import a_module`, you are and only are executing the `__init__.py` file in that module directory. If you want to access the `a_module.file`, you need to explicitly import it.

When you use `import a_file`, you are executing that file, as `path` is just a variable of `os`, so you can access it like `os.path`.

So the difference is, `path` is a variable in `os` while `towel_utils` is a submodule in `towel_stuff`. Or let's say `path` is an imported module in `os` which makes it become a variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Normally, for example if we want to use os.path, we don't need to write import os.path, but just import os is enough. So, with my built package, why do I have to give the full package path?

It all depends on how the module is constructed.  For example, if in your `towel_stuff` module you included:

```
from towel_stuff import towel_utils
```

Then code that imported only `towel_stuff` would have access to `towel_stuff.towel_utils` without additional imports.